# High Memory Usage?

Tags: memory

We have use for magento 1.8. Initially site was working fine. But in couple of weeks, we faced the some problems. Suddenly website is down. Once its restart the server, the website is working. And check with my support team they said site use high memory usage. We have 16 gb ram and 1tb hdd.

And we have around 9000 products and 100 product attributes and 60 categories around.

Please advise for this issue.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What OS is the server running? Is it shared? Any errors in the logs??

Answer (score 1):

You're going to check the server from the shell and check out the specs/performance. One of the major things you'll want to check is the used/available RAM.

Lastly, there's a nice site called Pingdom that helps diagnose slow-loading issues with sites that may be of use to see if there's any items on the actual pages causing the spikes.